# how do i find out about (and turn off) AmazonCloudWatch alarms?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have been getting some emails from AWS with warnings about usage of AmazonCloudWatch alarms (image attached also):
[image: amazon cloud watch alarm]

Apparently I have used 8.6 so far this month, but after trying to find out exactly what alarm I have enabled that is triggering I am coming up short.  Can anyone advise how to find out what these alarms are and how to turn them off?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To read of AWS Alarms Visit: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html

To see your current alarms, visit 'CloudWatch' service. Then on left panel you can see the 'Alarms' section. Here you can check your alarms, create new ones, disable or delete old ones.

See 'Alarm' section dashboard images on below link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NCvl.png